# Jordan form hard problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a matrix $P$ such that $J=P^{-1}AP$, where $J$ is the Jordan Form of the matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{1}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{-1}\\{0}&{1}&{1}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{1}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{1}&{1}&{0}&{0}&{0}\\{0}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{0}&{1}\\{0}&{-1}&{-1}&{-1}&{-1}&{0}&{1}&{-1}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}\end{bmatrix}$$

$p(x)=x(x-1)^{4}$ is the characteristic polynomial.  Then, the eigenvalues are $ (1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0)$

I'm trying to find the eigenvectors by this way $(A-I)z=w$ for the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ and $Ax=y$ for the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$. But this is impossible.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you calculate the characteristic polynomial? Haven't you made row/column transformations on the matrix? Based on those, $P$ might be recognizable.

Comment: @Berci          I calculate the characteristic polynimial by $det(A-xI)$ its easy because $det=tr(A-xI)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your characteristic polynomial. Maybe you want to enclose both terms in the $4^{th}$ power.

The CP is:

$$\lambda^8-4 \lambda^7+6 \lambda^6-4 \lambda^5+\lambda^4 = (\lambda-1)^4 \lambda^4$$

This leads to two eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 0$ with algebraic multiplicity 4.

For each, we arrive at two eigenvectors and two generalized eigenvectors (first two found normal way, last two generalized for each eigenvalue), that are:

- $v_1 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0), ~  \lambda_1 = 1$
- $v_2 = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ~  \lambda_2 = 1$
- $v_3 = (0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0), ~\lambda_3 = 1$
- $v_4 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ~\lambda_4 = 1$
- $v_5 = (0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0), ~ \lambda_5 = 0$
- $v_6 = (0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),  ~ \lambda_6 = 0$
- $v_7 = (0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), ~\lambda_7 = 0$
- $v_8 = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1),~ \lambda_8 = 0$

From the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we can write the Jordan Normal Form as:

$A = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Nice work + 1 $\quad \ddot\smile\quad$

Comment: Yes, indeed, lots of typing that would require...!

Comment: @user63192: No problem, make sure to work out the eigenvectors and understand how to derive them - especially the generalized ones. Regards

Comment: I CANNOT write such these matrices here with latex. Even writing with a pen is difficult so;...it shuld have many pluses. $+++++...+++~~\text{n-times}$

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend, I even know there is a way to better format the negative signs, but was too tired to look it up! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Here is aJordan form computed by maple

$$  \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} 1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0
&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1&1&0
&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0
&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end {array} \right] 
.$$

The eigenvalues are given by

$$ [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] $$

and the corresponding eigenvectors are the columns of the matrix

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} 0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\ 0
&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0
\\ -1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&0
&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&-1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&
1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end {array} \right] $$

Now, you should be able to construct $P$.

Comment: But the matrix J, must have four ones in the diagonal , no?

Comment: @user63192: You are very welcome.